# Max size of custom user attribute in keycloak

Tags: attributes, keycloak

What is the max size of a custom user attribute in KeyCloak? The [official doc](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/server_admin/topics/users/attributes.html) only describes how to create such attributes. If the size is limmited to 255 characters as default size of the string in a database then is there an ability to configure this size not modifying the source code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keycloak's attribute values maximum length is defined by its backend storage. The default setup uses PostgreSQL. Custom user attributes are stored in `user_attribute` table, which has `value` of type `varchar(255)`.

You may want to change the field type to `text`.
Please make sure to backup your database first.

`ALTER TABLE user_attribute ALTER COLUMN value TYPE TEXT;`